# Reinstall windows 7 on HP dv7t 7000 - Windows Setup could not configure Windows on this computer's hardware

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive-cache

I am trying to install windows 7 ultimate on my new laptop. The laptop shipped with windows 7 home premium, and has two hard drives. It has a 750gb and 32gb SSD. It was using the 32gb as a cache.

When I try to install windows now, I keep getting this error:
Windows Setup could not configure Windows on this computer's hardware

I imagine I need the raid drivers, but I'm not sure which drivers I need. I also don't know how I can install the drivers on the machine before windows installation.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to install Windows on, the HDD or SSD? (Personally I moved my installation to the SSD for better performance, but mine is a 120GB - you could put your OS on your HDD and store documents / programs on the HDD, but that's my opinion)

Comment: I'm trying to install on the 750gb